# how to round numbers up and down depending specefic condition in excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement

i am new to excel and i want to know ho to round numbers up and down depending on the second number after the decimal point. if the third number is equla or more than 5 add  1 to the second number and remove the third number else do remove the second number only

for example : 2.961 -> 2.96
: 2.968 -> 2.97
thanks by advance

Answer (score 2):

This is achieved simply using the [`ROUND()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/round-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c) function:

```
=ROUND(2.961,2) = 2.96
=ROUND(2.968,2) = 2.97
```

In this case, you are rounding to 2 decimal places (which is the second parameter).

From the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/round-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c):

> The ROUND function rounds a number to a specified number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to that and it is to use this button or icon to round numbers up or down u will find it in the home tools bar in desktop app [image]